# WSO2 ESB-How to pass dates with rest url

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

url likes:

```
http://ict.esg.ilfseducation.com`/gtrapi/api/profilesystem?`d1=17-10-2018&d2=17-10-2018
```

Iam trying this code to pass with dates dynamically d1 and d2 but not working.but how to pass dates with dynamically please any one suggest me.i have try this another url with sigle parms working fine.but dates was  not working any one please suggeat me.

api:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/gtrapi/api/profilesystem?" name="SCR_profileapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" protocol="http" uri-template="/{date1}/{date2}">
        <inSequence>
            <property description="http" name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="404"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="SCR_profileendpoint"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <switch source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                <case regex="200">
                    <log description="200log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="200reserrorcode"/>
                    </log>
                    <send/>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <log description="reslog" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </default>
            </switch>

            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <switch source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                <case regex="200">
                    <log description="200log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="200reserrorcode"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <log description="reslog" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </default>
            </switch>

            <send/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="SCR_profileendpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <http uri-template="http://ict.esg.ilfseducation.com/gtrapi/api/profilesystem?d1={uri.var.service.date1}&amp;d2={uri.var.service.d2}" method="get">
   </http>"/>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: If you want to pass the date as `/profilesystem?d1=17-10-2018&d2=17-10-2018` pattern, in your rest api, you have to set uri-template as follows; `uri-template="?d1={date1}&d2={date2}"`

Comment: it's Working  thank you so much @  Erandika Harshani

Comment: @ Erandika Harshani  how to pass this type urls..gvsckklibts.gvsl.com:9852/login?userData={userName:"raju",password:"raju@123"}

Comment: You can pass this as `{userName:"raju",password:"raju@123"} ` request body. Then you can get values on your api, using this; `<property name=”userName” expression=”json-eval($.userName)”/>` .

Comment: sorry i can't understand please  any some example @  Erandika Harshani